# Trouble with installing Rmpi on MacOS (bigSUR ver 11.6.1)

Tags: r, macos, mpi

I'm trying to install Rmpi on my macbook. However, I keep running into this error where `Rmpi.so` cannot be loaded. When I tried to load `Rmpi`, this is the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so, 6): Symbol not found: _ompi_mpi_2int
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so
```

The steps that I took was as follow: First I installed openmpi

```
brew install open-mpi
```

Then I installed Rmpi as follow:

```
R CMD INSTALL Rmpi_0.6-9.2.tar.gz --configure-args="--with-Rmpi-include=/opt/homebrew/include --with-Rmpi-libpath=/opt/homebrew/lib --with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI" --no-test-load
```

I've tried to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Rmpi/libs/Rmpi.so` but this does not work either. Is there a way to fix this?

this is my session info:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 parallel_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0
```

Comment: you are using `R` built for `x86_64`, but the path `/opt/homebrew` suggests you are using `brew` for `M1`. Assuming you are using a `M1` processor, try sticking to ARM binaries: `brew install R` and then reinstall `Rmpi` with `/opt/homebrew/bin/R`

Comment: Some time ago I was struggling with `Rmpi` as well. Here is the summary of my fight: https://www.owsiak.org/r3-4-openmpi-3-0-0-rmpi-inside-macos-little-bit-of-mess/